# PHP - Displaying database data in 2 different tables

Tags: php

I need to display data from a database in a table, and I was wondering if you can create 2 separate tables based on a variable.

I have code to display it all in one table:

```
        <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Name </th>
                        <th> Event </th>
                    </tr>
            <?php
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <?php echo $row["name"] ?> </td>   
                        <td> <?php echo $row["event"] ?> </td>
                    </tr>       
     <?php } ?>
     </table>
```

So each person has an option of 2 fundraisers. Is there a way to create 2 separate tables based on the event variable? I know I could create another table in the database, but I want to keep all the data in one area.

I only know basic PHP and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well you could create two while loop. are the tables supose to be the same ?

Comment: @Nicolas no... I'm having a hard time explaining this. So the database has a bunch of names and each name has an event with it. There are only 2 event options, and I want 2 different tables that display data from the same database, but one table shows names with event X while the other shows names with event Y.

Comment: Oh, i would suggest splitting you array in two, one for the X and one for the Y, before printing it. Then you can iterate through both arrays and print them to the correct place.

Comment: @Nicolas That's what I'm trying to get away from. The way I have my sign-up form made needs it to all be in one place.

Comment: In this case, you could use Javascript / Jquery to iterate throught a JSON array made out of your PHP array ( `json_encode`) and then you check if the event is X or Y and you append to the correct table. that's what i would do.

Comment: @Nicolas Ok I will look into that, Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Name </th>
                    <th> Event </th>
                </tr>
        <?php
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $row["name"] ?> </td>   

                </tr>       
 <?php } ?>
 </table>
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Name </th>
                    <th> Event </th>
                </tr>
        <?php
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {?>
                <tr>

                    <td> <?php echo $row["event"] ?> </td>
                </tr>       
 <?php } ?>
 </table>
```